# How can MFC get the text-box string form a Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt, mfc, qt4, qwidget

I want to use MFC to get the content of the text-box which is from the application using Qt4.

I tried hard to solve this issue, but I only get the hWnd of main window of Qt application so far.

when I used EnumChildWindows, nothing was happened.

Is there any way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Try to get hwnd of text box. All QWidgets have winId() method. Try to use it.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the application's interface with Microsoft's Spy++?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to your problem:

First is to use the Microsoft User Interface Automation (UIA) API to access the application. AFAIK Qt supports that API.

Second is to create a connection between the application that you can use for communication. Read about Inter Process Communication (IPC).